# Firebase - getValue() with custom field name

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example I use at Firebase Database field with name "key" and would like (for any reason) to name it "id" in Java object.

How this can be done when using Firebase dataSnapshot.getValue(Class)?
I tried using Jackson annotation such as:

```
@JsonProperty("key")
Long id;
```

but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Firebase v3, as of June 27th,  you should now use @PropertyName instead.  See https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Comment: Can you (or @Tajchert) let me know if this actually works for you? I've seen mixed reports about it and haven't had/taken time to verify it myself yet.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I can confirm it does work.
Thanks guys.